# Symmetry Definition and Equation

Tags: symmetry

I need some help to understand Inversian Symmetry, Conformal Symmetry, and Scale Symmetry. Could you give me some guideline?

Comment: You should make your question more specific.

Comment: I mean that I don't understand what is the definition of those symmetries. I have try to look it up online but I found none. I want to know about what they are.

Comment: So are you asking what the analytical deffinitions are, or are you asking about their geometrical sense?

Comment: Both would help me a lots. I need to understand it before I can do my homework which is about those kinds of symmetries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inversion symmetry is inversion with respect to a circle, which maps its inside to the outside and vice versa. You can read about it [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InversePoints.html). The inversion symmetry is a conformal symmetry. In the complex line, an inversion is a Mobius transformation.

The scaling symmetry is just scaling invariance or invariance under maps of the kind $x\to ax, a\not=0$. When you consider negative constants they also realize a reflection (i.e. change the orientation). Scalings are conformal symmetries.

The conformal symmetries preserve oriented angles between curves. They are all scalings, translations, rotations, [special conformal symmetries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_conformal_transformation) or a combination of those. All isometries are conformal. Analytically, a transformation $x\to y$ is conformal if $x\to y=a(x)^2x$ where $a$ is a smooth function. In the complex line, they are scalings, inversions, rotations and translations. In other words the conformal group of the complex line coincides with the Mobius group.

Comment: You are wellcome. If you liked my answer you can also upvote it.

Comment: I would like to vote for you. But I need to have at least 15 reputation. Now I have 3. Sorry about that.